# Intermittent failure when clicking "Allow Access to All Photos" button in iOS App,mistakenly clicking "Don't Allow" instead, using Appium iOS

Tags: ios, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios, xcuitest

I am writing automation tests for an iOS App, where it requires access to 'Select Photos...', 'Allow Access to All Photos', and 'Don't Allow'. I am using Appium 2.0 with Webdriver.io, running on BrowserStack with an iOS 16.3 device.

Initially, I used the '`name`' locator strategy for the '`Allow Access to All Photos`' button, as it is unique. It worked for a couple of times and then started failing intermittently. When I checked the execution video, it's actually clicking the 'Don't Allow' button.

So, I changed the locator strategy to use the iOS Predicate as follows: `type == "XCUIElementTypeButton" AND label == "Allow Access to All Photos" AND name == "Allow Access to All Photos"`. However, it still fails intermittently with the **error: "Error: element ("-ios predicate string:type == "XCUIElementTypeButton" AND label == "Allow Access to All Photos" AND name == "Allow Access to All Photos"") still not displayed after 10000ms"**, but it's actually clicking the 'Don't Allow' button in the video.

```
const allowAccessToAllPhotosButton = await this.allowAccessToAllPhotosButton;
await allowAccessToAllPhotosButton.waitForDisplayed();
await allowAccessToAllPhotosButton.click();

get allowAccessToAllPhotosButton(): Promise<WebdriverIO.Element> {
    return getElementByPredicate(IOSPredicate.ALLOW_ACCESS_TO_ALL_PHOTOS_BUTTON);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the **autoAcceptAlerts** **bstack:options** capability, and see if it's auto-accepting the popup or not. For ref.: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/advanced-features/handle-permission-pop-ups